# Why is Perl hash value added as a key?

Tags: perl

I have a hash `my %read_data = ();`

I am trying to build up keys and values like this

```
$read_data{"status"} = 0;
$read_data{"suffix"} = "_SP";
$read_data{"consumption"} = 95;
```

What I am seeing is as follows, and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
Key=status
Key=0
Key=suffix
Key=_SP
Key=consumption
Key=95
```

I am printing this using

```
for my $k1 (%read_data)
{
  print "Key=".$k1."\n";
}
```

Comment: You've show us your input, but not the code you use to generate the output.

Comment: I forgot the keys keyword as well as what generated the debug output. All taken care of in OP.

Comment: `my %read_data = ();` is better written as `my %read_data;`

Comment: @BradGilbert Yes but what happens if you have strict turned on?

Comment: `my %read_data = ();` and `my %read_data;` are **equivalent**. Also you should **always** have [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the beginning of your Perl files; until you know **exactly** why they are recommended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a relationship between arrays and hashes that you're hitting:

```
my %hash = ( one => 1, two => 2, three => 3 );
```

This creates a three member hash with the keys `one`, `two`, and `three. So does this:

```
my %hash = ( "one", 1, "two", 2, "three", 3 );
```

In fact, these two lines are exactly the same statement. The `=>` is a form of *syntactic sugar* used to highlight the relationship between one value and another. Here's the same line again. I'm just messing with your brain in this one, but it produces the same hash as before:

```
my %hash = ( "one", 1 => "two", 2 => "three", 3 );
```

Here's another way of assigning the same hash:

```
my @array = ( "one", 1, "two", 2, "three", 3 );
my %hash = @array;
```

And this is also valid too:

```
my @array = %hash;
```

There's a strong relationship between hashes and arrays in Perl. If you take an array in a hash context, it becomes a hash. If you take a hash in an array context, it becomes an array. 
For example:

```
 mysub (%hash);

sub mysub {
    my %subhash = @_;
    ...
}
```

This is a valid (although not recommended way) of passing a hash to a subroutine. The hash is translated into the `@_`array which then gets translated back to a hash in the subroutine.

Let's take a look at your loop:

```
for my $k1 (%read_data) {
```

The `(...)` is a list/array context, and thus will take your `%read_data` hash, and present it in a list context with each *key* followed by its *value*.

There are a few ways to fix this. One is to use the [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) to pull out all of the keys in a hash and return an array of the keys. This is usually combined with [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) to sort the keys into some semblance of order.

```
for my $k1 ( sort keys %read_data ) {
```

Another is to use the [each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) which returns a series of two member arrays with one key and one value.

Comment: There's no such thing as "an array in hash context." When you say `my %hash = @array` you're using an array to _initialize_ a hash.

Comment: About the only thing I would add, is that sometimes you don't need to know the key, and the order doesn't matter. In that case you would just loop over the [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html).

Answer (score 6):

While it would need you posting your code to make certain, judging by the output you appear to be iterating the hash as though it were an array; Perl will let you do this, but it's almost never what you want. Instead, try something like this:

```
foreach my $key (keys %read_data) {
  my $value = $read_data{$key};
  print "$key = $value\n";
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a `foreach` over a hash will get its keys and values sequentially, so don't do that.

This worked for me:

```
while (my ($k, $v) = each %read_data) {
    print "$k = $v\n";
}
```

(I vastly prefer getting hash *entries* rather than hash *keys* which then have to be looked up again.)